# Why does numpy.savez() output non reproducible files?

Tags: python, numpy, zip

The function [`numpy.savez()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html) allows to store numpy objects in a file. Storing the same same object in two files results in two different files:

```
import numpy as np
some_array = np.arange(42)
np.savez('/tmp/file1', some_array=some_array)
np.savez('/tmp/file2', some_array=some_array)
```

The two files differ:

```
$ diff /tmp/file1.npz /tmp/file2.npz 
Binary files /tmp/file1.npz and /tmp/file2.npz differ
```

Why aren't the files identical? Is there some random behavior, filename or time stamp included? Can this be workaround or fixed? (Is it a bug?)

Note that this is not the case for [`np.save()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html). Files produced by `np.save()` are identical for identical inputs. So I guess it is related to zipping of the data.

AFAICS there are only two bits different:

```
$ xxd /tmp/file1.npz > /tmp/file1.hex
$ xxd /tmp/file2.npz > /tmp/file2.hex
$ diff -u0 /tmp/file1.hex /tmp/file2.hex    
--- /tmp/file1.hex      2018-03-13 13:39:12.235897095 +0100
+++ /tmp/file2.hex      2018-03-13 13:39:08.743927081 +0100
@@ -1 +1 @@
-0000000: 504b 0304 1400 0000 0000 ce6c 6d4c 9c9d  PK.........lmL..
+0000000: 504b 0304 1400 0000 0000 cf6c 6d4c 9c9d  PK.........lmL..
@@ -30 +30 @@
-00001d0: 1403 1400 0000 0000 ce6c 6d4c 9c9d 6ad9  .........lmL..j.
+00001d0: 1403 1400 0000 0000 cf6c 6d4c 9c9d 6ad9  .........lmL..j.
```

I can't find any good hint in the [implementation of the function](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/e97de95d4cae6805ed6c258655e7492a5f2ce863/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L669), but I haven't checked the zipping code yet (also Python 3.6 might make a difference).

**Note:** Tested with Python 2.7 and numpy 1.9.2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an github-issue about this [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9439):

> savez() is not deterministic #9439

which seems to boil down to *Zip files attaching timestamps to files* (as you guessed) in combination with the usage of temporary-files.

Workarounds are discussed too, but it seems this issue is still *open* (although Python>=3.6.0 might be [unaffected](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/9863) now (which again seems to be observed by you)).

Comment: Ah _deterministic_ is the right keyword I was looking for, not _reproducible_... Thanks! :) I still don't understand how the timestamp can change only two bits, but maybe not too important.

Comment: (In regards to the bit-change) That's surely not my area of expertise. But it seems it's heavily based on the unit of seconds (and it seems with limited precision: 2 secs) and a two bit-change might seem plausible for some experiments which you might have done. This is something which probably can easily be analyzed reading zip's design. Maybe starting with [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)), which indicates a 2 byte timestamp.

Comment: You are absolutely right. A unit of "2 seconds" seems to be surprising, but a simple experiment confirms your theory: when putting a sleep(20) in between, I get a difference of 0xf9 - 0xef = 10.